# Magento REST API - How to determine the API base URL?

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm running Magento 2.2.5 and was having trouble working out what the URL was for making API requests. For example to GET a list of countries I had seen the following syntax used:

```
/rest/default/V1/directory/countries
```

which has worked on some stores, but I was getting this error:

```
{
"message" : "Specified request cannot be processed.",
"trace" : null
}
```

I started playing around with the URL format and removed the "default" and used this instead:

```
/rest/V1/directory/countries
```

and the requests were then successful. How does one determine what the base URL to use for Magento REST API requests? I haven't been able to find this documented so far.

Comment: THIS!!! THIS is *exactly* why I hate Magento....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax of Magento 2 Api is

> *http://<:host:>/rest/<:store_code:>/<:api_path:>*

Here `store_code` can be any one of the "store view" of your Magento2 instance. You can get the store code in admin panel. You can use `store_code` to get information specific to that Store View via API. By default Magento2 installation comes with 1 website, 1 store & 1 store view (this store-view has code "***default***", in your case this might have changed hence you get the error).

The architecture can be understand with the help of image
[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC6yW.png)
Ref: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/websites-stores-views.html

- When you specify `store_code` it checks information for that particular Store-View. If the specified `store_code` is not found in the database, Api returns *"Specified request cannot be processed."* message.
- When you do not specify `store_code` it first finds default **Website**, then finds default **Store** for this Website & then finds default **Store View** Associated to this Store. And finally it returns information for this default Store-View. The association of default store & store-view can be changed from admin panel.
  [Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41jY1.png)

Hence the URL for API should be below in case you need store specific information. `store_code` can be set to **`all`** if you need information for all the stores.

> *http://<:host:>/rest/<:store_code:>/<:api_path:>*